# finding local behaviour as x tends to $0^+$ of particular solution of ode

Tags: asymptotics

we have

$$ y' + xy = \cos x $$

I am asked to find the first three terms in local behaviour as $x \to 0^+$.

#### thought:

As $ x \to 0^+$, then $\cos x \sim 1 $ so

$$ y' + xy \sim 1 $$

which can be solved by using integrating factor $e^{x^2/2}$, thus

$$ ( e^{x^2/2} y ) \sim \int e^{x^2/2} = \int \sum \frac{x^{2n} }{2^n n!} = \sum \frac{x^{2n+1} }{2^n (2n+1) n!} \sim x$$

thus,

$$ y(x) \sim cx e^{-x^2/2} $$

is this a correct?

Comment: If you wait to solve the DE before using an approximation you get a different result of $(c+x)e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: That is what I obtained by letting $e^{x^2/2}\cos x\approx 1$.

Comment: Another way to do it: start with $y(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + \ldots$ and use $\cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2 + \ldots$ and try to match the coefficients of $x^n$ on each side of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
y^\prime+xy=\cos x
\end{equation}

Let $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
y^\prime+xy&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}

Replacing each $n$ in the first sum with $n+1$ and each $n$ in the second with $n-1$ yields

\begin{eqnarray}
y^\prime+xy&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)c_{n+1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n-1}x^{n}\\
&=&c_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_{n-1}\right]x^n
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore the DE can be written in summation form

\begin{equation}
c_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_{n-1}\right]x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\end{equation}

Immediately we see that $c_1=1$, so we know that the first two terms of the solution are $y=c_0+x.$ Now, when $n=1$ the coefficient of $x$ in the cosine expansion must be $0$ so we know that $(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_{n-1}=2c_2+c_0=0$. Therefore, $c_2=-\frac{1}{2}c_0$. Thus we now have the first three terms as required

\begin{equation}
y=c_0+x-\frac{1}{2}c_0x^2
\end{equation}

Since we are on a roll, let's find the fourth term of $y$.

When $n=2$ we get $(n+1)c_{n+1}+c_{n-1}=3c_3+c_1=-\frac{1}{2}$, the coefficient of $x$ in the cosine expansion. We already know that $c_1=1$ so we have $c_3=-\frac{1}{2}$ in the expansion of $y$. Therefore we have the first four terms:

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&c_0+x-\frac{1}{2}c_0x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^3\\
&=&(c_0+x)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks to @Winther for the hint.